# A question about "rearranging" finite unions.

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

I am working on this simple problem:

> Show that
> $$\overline{A\cup B}=\overline{A} \cup \overline{B}$$
> where $\overline{X}$ denotes the closure of $X$.

Now I have already proved it by showing that LHS is a subset of RHS and vice-versa and using the fact that a finite union or intersection of closed sets is closed. I'm wondering if it can't be solved in an even more direct way as follows:

Let $L_{X}$ denote the set of all limit points of the set $X$. Then $\overline{A\cup B}=(A\cup B)\cup L_{A\cup B}$. $L_{A\cup B}=L_{A}\cup L_{B}$, so $\overline{A\cup B}=(A\cup B)\cup (L_{A}\cup L_{B})$. Now can I write this expression as $(A\cup L_{A})\cup(B\cup L_{B})$ so that it becomes $\overline{A}\cup\overline{B}$, which is what I need?

Apologies if this seems like a trivial question.

Comment: I would say that using  just open and closed sets is moer 'direct' than using limit polints.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy, I agree with you, but in my opinion it seems that exploiting the definition of closure in the way I've done(if it's allowed) is somehow more intuitive for me.

Comment: Your approach is correct, but you need a *proof* for $L_{A \cup B} = L_A  \cup L_B$. I do not see that this easier than proving $\overline{A\cup B}=\overline{A} \cup \overline{B}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Union is indeed a commutative and associative operation on sets (well known from set theory, we use set theory all the time in topology), and denoting the set of limit points of any set $C$ by $C'$, as is more common, you can indeed say

$$\overline{A \cup B} = (A \cup B) \cup (A\cup B)' = (A \cup B) \cup (A'\cup B')= (A \cup A') \cup (B \cup B)' = \overline{A} \cup \overline{B}$$

provided you indeed know that limit points sets are preserved by finite unions.

An alternative proof using not limt points but the definition of a $\overline{C}$ as the smallest (by inclusion) closed superset of $C$:

$\overline{A} \cup \overline{B}$ is closed (as finite sets are closed under finite unions which follows (by de Morgan) from the fact that finite intersections of open sets are open). It contains $A \cup B$ trivially, so by minimality $\overline{A \cup B} \subseteq \overline{A} \cup \overline{B}$. OTOH: $A \subseteq A \cup B$ so $\overline{A} \subseteq \overline{A \cup B}$ and also $B \subseteq A \cup B$ so $\overline{B} \subseteq \overline{A \cup B}$, and combine these to give $\overline{A} \cup \overline{B} \subseteq \overline{A \cup B}$ and we have both inclusions and equality.

Comment: So is it always true that $(A\cup B)'=A'\cup B'$?. 

Also thanks for bringing up the question of notation - it's just that I wanted to avoid $A'$ because during my school days we used to study Boolean algebra, where complements were denoted by primes on superscript. Edit: Oh, and yes that is exactly how I've proved it the way you showed in your edit.

Comment: @tmaj Yes, I assumed that you already knew this from your question.. Sometimes $\rm{der}(A)$ is also used (for *derived set*, an old-fashioned name for the set of limit points. The prime is also used for derivative, right? Context will be clear on whether you're doing Boolean algebra or Topology, so confusion will rarely ensue.